# Windows server performance monitoring tool with email

Tags: windows-server-2008, performance-monitor

We have an SQL server 2005 on Windows Server 2008. SQL server performance is not consistent through out the day. For example, a procedure that takes less than 5 seconds usually, takes around 30 to 45 seconds sometimes. In a few cases, this procedures has taken even 180 seconds. When we did a little bit of troubleshooting, we felt, though not sure, that the was hardly any load on the server.

So to understand what is/are causing the server become slow, we thought of monitoring disk space, memory, cup load etc for 24/7. We found powershell scripts at this link and used them. But they are not polished and do not seem work well. Any ideas, pointers to help us monitor this server for its heath is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have used Paessler PRTG for this and it is easy to install and configure using WMI and SNMP (Among other things) The free version will give 10 sensor and a simple update will get you 20 sensors and there is a free trial of the full product.  Supports e-mail alerts if certain conditions defined by you are met. Helped us identify issues quickly. [PRTG](http://www.paessler.com/tools)

Comment: I installed this application and configured it with 8 sensors. It is working quite well. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not like PerfMon, there is also [XPerf](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/pigscanfly/xperf-a-new-tool-in-the-windows-sdk) for the "hardcore" among us.  I am still trying to get through the documentation . . . eventually.

Comment: Though this seems promising, the download page talked about a few issues with the download of SDK. So I did not do this as it is a production level server.

Answer (score 0):

The standard Windows performance monitor application is capable of monitoring servers through the network.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind the tool and I am long time RDS/TS expert :-)

Check the [Syskit](https://www.syskit.com/) it can connect to the server and extract info aobut the performance of all applications. The application is commercial but mention you read about it on the super user and mention me so I will tell guys to provide good discount :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with standard windows tools like Windows Performance Monitor (should be already installed on your server). You can set them up to collect data throughout the day so that you can review them for bottlenecks later on.

You can also set it up to generate email alerts. See this [step-by-step instruction](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2424491) by microsoft.

There are also plenty of other tools available for this purpose. I have compiled a [list of windows server performance monitoring tools](https://checkpanel.com/resources/windows-server-performance-monitoring-tools) (40 of them) which should give you a good overview.

Comment: This question is 5 years old. Was that available on Server 2008? Though that list is nice I'm not sure this is a good question to post it on.

Comment: Performance Monitor and Task Scheduler are available on Windows Server 2008. I'm not 100% sure if the step-by-step instructions are identical for Server 2008, although the article bears a date of 2011. Since all components are available I believe one should at least be able to get the idea even if the actual steps might differ.